# Specify username, password and connection URL for embedded database in Hibernate/JPA2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.1

I have this database defined in java config as follows:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("classpath:/db/sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:/db/sql/insert-data.sql")
            .build();
}
```

I need to specify username and password for this configuration, but they are hardcoded somewhere deep inside this builder's classes. How can I specify my custom connection details?

If it matters, my full class looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Resource
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("classpath:/db/sql/create-db.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:/db/sql/insert-data.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
...
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
...
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
...
        return factory;
    }

    Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        ...
        return props;
    }
}
```

and my main configuration file as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.myapp.conf"})
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {CustomerRepository.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
})
public class ApplicationConfig {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You run the database in **embedded mode**. The current jvm has exclusive access to the db. It's not possible to provide a login in embedded mode.
You don't need to provide credentials unless you run in server mode and want to provide remote connections.

See [H2 connection modes](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I managed to do it:  Make a copy of the `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.SimpleDriverDataSourceFactory` that ignores the values set outside:

```
  final class SimpleDriverDataSourceFactory implements DataSourceFactory {

    private final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();

    @Override
    public ConnectionProperties getConnectionProperties() {
      return new ConnectionProperties() {
        @Override
        public void setDriverClass(Class<? extends Driver> driverClass) {
          dataSource.setDriverClass(driverClass);
        }

        @Override
        public void setUrl(String url) {
          dataSource.setUrl(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void setUsername(String username) {
          // override the sa user
          dataSource.setUsername( "myusername" );
        }

        @Override
        public void setPassword(String password) {
          // override the empty password
          dataSource.setPassword( "mypassword" );
        }
      };
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
      return this.dataSource;
    }
  }
```

Now just use that in your builder:

```
SimpleDriverDataSourceFactory factory = new SimpleDriverDataSourceFactory();

EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
  .setName("mydatabase")
  .setDataSourceFactory( factory )
  .build();
return db;
```

Not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, as you said embedded databases such as hsqldb or h2 have hard coded user name and password ("sa" and "") used to access it from memory (jdbc:hsqldb:mem: for hsqldb).

If you want to change credentials, you should a database like Postgres or mySQL and creating a new datasource (for example with `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`). This way you could set your wanted properties.

Comment: what if I want to change connection URL? For instance, add some parameters to connection URL?